# can't find "ntxsym" font file

Tags: fonts, ps2pdf

Been away for ~10 days -- came home to find a couple of packages on my LaTeX install (MikTeX latest, Win 10 pro) needed updating, including newtx, which I use as the primary font for many of my documents.

I tried compiling a document that pre-upgrade compiled without warning/error. But, post-update, I now get the following when rendering from the .ps -> .pdf file using ps2pdf:

```
 Querying operating system for font files...
 Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/%rom%R.
 Can't find (or can't open) font file ntxsym.
 Didn't find this font on the system!
 Substituting font Courier for ntxsym.
```

Did a quick search, and was surprised to find not a single mention of 'font file ntxsym' anywhere. So, perhaps *not* surprised ps2pdf couldn't find the  font file, since even the almighty and omnipotent Google search engine hasn't either. ;-)

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the problem as described arose as an artifact of changes in how newtx interprets/uses AMS symbol arguments I was passing to newtx. I had been successfully using the following as part of my preamble (my larger documents usually have anywhere from 20-30 packages involved, so sussing out weird interactions can be time consuming).

```
% use AMS math package for more control over equations
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% use following for better formed clones of Times
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces,nosymbolsc]{newtxmath}
 \usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}
```

The problem was that recent changes to newtx, in particular newtexmath which supports its own AMS symbol set,conflicted in some funky way with the amssymb package. So, tweak

```
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces,nosymbolsc]{newtxmath}
```

to

```
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces,noamssymbols]{newpxmath}
```

and...problem solved.